# How do I click a button using JQuery that only has 'Data-capture' and no class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the button code.
It doesn't have a class, but `data-capture` attribute is `button123`. Is there some way to identify it using JQuery and click it?

```
<button data-capture="button123" type="button">
    <span>Button123</span>
    <svg class="icon--standard icon--xpm svgicon x" viewBox="0 0 19 19">
         <path class="svg__bg" d="M0 0h19v19h-19z"></path>
         <path class="svg__fg path--vbar" d="M9 4h1v11h-1z"></path>
         <path class="svg__fg path--hbar" d="M4 9h11v1h-11z"></path></svg><span class="xyz123 abc123">
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Instead of a class, you can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `[data-capture="button123"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

native javascript:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button[data-capture=button123]");
//or
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-capture=button123]");
```

jquery:

```
var buttons = $("button[data-capture=button123]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button[data-capture=button123]").click(function(){
    ...some code on click
});
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, a single line is fine, but it is needed. I've arrived here from a moderation queue because this was automatically flagged. Keeping answers to high quality will help prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

```
$('button[data-capture="button123"]').click();
```

Longer answer is: you select the set of buttons (in your case it is a set containing a single element, namely the button to be clicked) and calls the click function for it. You can use the attribute equals selector like that in the future as well:

```
[attributename="value"]
```